# Is it possible to return a string from a .net program using vba

Tags: vb.net, vba

I have this vba code

```
Dim strpath As String
Dim this As String
strpath = "C:\Users\johbra\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsApplication6\WindowsApplication6\bin\Debug\WindowsApplication6.exe"
this = Shell(strpath)

MsgBox this
```

I also have this function in a .net program

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    dothis()
    Application.Exit()

End Sub

Function dothis()
    Return "HI"
End Function
End Class
```

Im trying to get the vba code to give me a messagebox that says "HI".. Is this possible?

Comment: The Shell command can accept other parameters, check them out, maybe it will solve your problem.

Comment: The line `Return "HI"` returns the text back to whatever called the function, not back to the caller of the application.

Comment: Also `Shell(strpath)` returns a number (the pID of the newly started process iirc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most accepted and reliable way to call .NET code from VBA is to expose the .NET class as a COM class (no extra code needed, just tick the appropriate box in project properties), then add a reference the COM class in your VBA project, the way you would for any other other COM class, and call the function.

[Here's a guide on how exactly this is done.](http://richnewman.wordpress.com/2007/04/15/a-beginner%E2%80%99s-guide-to-calling-a-net-library-from-excel/)

Please let me know if you need more details on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to try this with command line parameters.

Like:

```
    Dim CommandLineArgs As System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of String) = My.Application.CommandLineArgs

    For i As Integer = 0 To CommandLineArgs.Count - 1
        MessageBox.Show(CommandLineArgs(i))
    Next
```

To pass parameters back to the VBA script;

```
         Console.WriteLine("Message")
```

Can catch the console outcome in your VBA code...

Comment: wouldn't that show the messagebox inside the .net program... i am trying to bring the string back to the vba code.